# Updating a Google Sheet with the SID result from Twilio

Tags: python, twilio, gspread

I am creating a Google Sheet that will have names and numbers to text people. I am using python ( I'm an amateur),gspread,twilio and I want to update the spreadsheet with the resulting SID number by each phone number. This is the code I have created so far.

```html
import gspread
import json
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import datetime
from twilio.rest import Client
#create client
account = "xxxx"
token  = "xxxx"
client = Client(account, token)

# connect google spreadsheet and return worksheet info
gc=gspread.service_account()
sh = gc.open("Twilio")
wk = sh.worksheet("SMS")
worksheet = sh.worksheet("SMS")
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
print(type(worksheet))
# get cell value from worksheet(ws)

# Loop through the names and numbers and send a text message to each phone number 
names = wk.batch_get(('a2:a',))[0]
numbers = wk.batch_get(('c2:c',))[0]

for i in range(len(names)):

# send a message to a recipient_number
# add recipient name to the message
    message = client.messages.create(
        from_="+18447011479",
        to = numbers[i],
        body=f"Hello {names[i][0]}, this is a test message from Twilio.",
    media_url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dianephan/flask_upload_photos/main/UPLOADS/DRAW_THE_OWL_MEME.png",)

# Update sheet Column D with SID results
#worksheet.update stuck here
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I will have  a list of names in Google Sheeets that will receive a text. Twilio receives a SID confirmation number when they send the text. I want to take that unique number and place it in the row next the the phone number so I know the person received the text.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.